# Meteor external API calls limit the calls or Sleep?

Tags: meteor

I wasn't able to find any information on how you can sleep for 1 second or limit the amount of calls per some time in meteor or javascript seems like there is no simple sleep function? Here is my code how should I go about limiting or sleeping the right way? (Or should I just hack my way on doing this?) all tips are welcome!

```
call = function(method, endpoint, params) {
  try {
    params = _.extend({}, params || {});
    var data = HTTP.call(method, endpoint, {data: params});
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch call " + err.message);
  }
};
```

Comment: How about setTimeout() function?

Comment: @Sindis it will be good fit for server side?

Comment: I think it will, never user it tho, but saw some examples. That's why I'm jsut commenting it, not giving an answer

Comment: It stays in documentation that this function can be created anywhere http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/timers

Comment: @Sindis Ha I was just looking at it thanks! Now I can be sure it's safe to use thanks a lot! I found it with your help! Wonder if can use it inside a function or only outside arghh...

Comment: Glad it worked, I'll just make an answer then

Comment: Maybe underscore's [throttle](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle) function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, So supposedly there is undocumented server only sleep function in Meteor `Meteor._sleepForMs(5000);` simpler than using setTimeout function. I didn't choose what I will pick but this might help somebody else as well.

Comment: Beware that this is a server-only function - it doesn't exist on the client!

Answer (score 0):

Good way to make pauses or intervals in Meteor is to use Timers, such as [setTimeout()](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_settimeout)
or [setInterval()](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_setinterval)

Comment: can you help me integrate this also to my function? I guess I have to do wrap it into another function? Or is there a simple way?

Comment: Didn't check it cause I gotta go, but it should be something like Meteor.setTimeout(function(){//your code you want to timeout},500//time in ms to wait);

Comment: it's actually an issue... wrapping it into function will return instantly the data undefined and run it in 1 second I have to stop and return only when I have data like it works without the `setTimeout` http://pastebin.com/avfLU6Pa

Comment: Try making if statement with subscription